# How to pass an alt attribute in an on click method

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, alt

Hello I have the following code:

```
<img alt="image321" onclick="image(//here i want to pass the alt attribute to my function Bild()//);" src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/${videoId}/hqdefault.jpg" />


<script>
        function image(alt){
            
            alert(alt.src);
            
        }
</script>
```

I have my image and have given it an alt attribute with the value "image321".Now I want to pass this value to my function image() and output the value with alert as soon as I clicked on the image. But the output is always undifined.  Could someone please help me how to solve this problem.
Many greetings Nils

Answer (score 2):

First thing would be to [avoid inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045) - they have quite a few problems, too many to be worth using nowadays, such as a demented scope chain and quote escaping issues. Attach event listeners properly using Javascript with `addEventListener` instead.

Inside the listener, reference `this` to get to the clicked element, and its `src` property to get to its `src`:

```js
document.querySelector('img').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(this.src);
  console.log(this.alt);
});
```

```html
<img alt="image321" src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/${videoId}/hqdefault.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `this`, which sends the element that you run the function with.

Here is an example:

```js
function image(alt) {
alert(alt.src);
}
```

```html
<img alt="image321" src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/${videoId}/hqdefault.jpg" onclick="image(this)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myfunc(img){
            
            alert(img.alt);
            
        }
```

```html
<img alt="image321" onclick="myfunc(this);" src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/${videoId}/hqdefault.jpg" />
```